# How to launch java executives from bash directly

Tags: java, bash

If I want to launch one java executable `java --jar sample.jar` from command line, how could I write the bash script? The following doesn' work

```
#!/usr/bin/java 
--jar $HOME/tools/sample.jar
```

Answer (score 7):

```
#!/bin/sh
java --jar $HOME/tools/sample.jar
```

Java is NOT an interpreter and only a script interpreter can be used in the shebang(`#!`)

---

To be complete you cant pass parameters to the interpreter that way anyway..

The "correct" but still wrong way would have been

```
#!/usr/bin/java --jar 
$HOME/tools/sample.jar
```

---

I am not fully clear, but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) hints that the second method might just work..

> However, it is up to the interpreter to ignore the shebang line; thus, a script consisting of the following two lines simply echos both lines to standard output when run:

```
#!/bin/cat
Hello world!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

exec java -jar /path/to/jar/the-file.jar "$@"
```

With **$@** you pass the **bash arguments** to jar file